# How apply texture in this cube?

Tags: python, graphics, pyopengl

I'm trying to apply a texture to a cube that I created using matrix operations (translate and scale), but it's not working and need that make using matrix operations only, not vertex or lines.

A snippet of my code

```
textures = { 'notebook' : None }

def draw_notebook(texture):

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(0.0, -1.3, 5)
glScale(2.0,0.0,1.0)
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
glutSolidCube(1.0)
glPopMatrix()

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

def draws(): 
draw_notebook(textures['notebook'])

def load_texture(image): 

textureSurface = pygame.image.load(image) textureData = pygame.image.tostring(textureSurface, "RGBA", 1) width = textureSurface.get_width() height = textureSurface.get_height()

texid = glGenTextures(1)

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE)

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData)

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

return texid

def main(): 
textures['notebook'] = load_texture("textures\myimage.png")

main()
```